# How can I add rel="nofollow" attributes on RSS widgets?

Tags: plugins, rss

By default WordPress does not appear to have the option to add `rel="nofollow"` attributes on the RSS widgets.

```
<li>
    <a class="rsswidget" href="http://news.google.com/news/url...">
        The 60-Something Entrepreneur
    </a>
</li>
```

How can I make it so my RSS feed links have the `rel="nofollow"` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no way to do that. You could filter `'clean_url'` (like I did [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/38335/73)), but I don't see a simple way to deactivate the filter when the RSS widget is rendered.

You could [open a ticket on Trac](http://codex.wordpress.org/Reporting_Bugs) and ask for a filter in `wp_widget_rss_output()` … from my experience wasted time, but there is no third option.