# How do I add custom attributes to javascript tags in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript

I am looking to enable CloudFlare's RocketLoader feature that enables asynchronous loading of Javascript for my Wordpress site. The problem, however, is that there is one plugin for  that I want to be loaded normally.

From a technical point of view, according to https://www.cloudflare.com/wiki/Rocket_Loader, I simply need to change any script tag I want ignored to have the `data-cfasync="false"` attribute as follows: `<script data-cfasync="false" src="/javascript.js"></script>`

Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to do this for plugins that are automatically loaded by Wordpress.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can I close your question as a duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/38319/73? The answer there will solve your problem too.

Comment: I just took a look at it, but I actually don't understand the solution. I may need an interpretation...

Answer (score 2):

The following solution assumes that your plugins are using [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to insert scripts into the HTML code. If they don't they are broken by design and we cannot change the script tag.

This code works like the one in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/38335/73), in fact, it is almost a duplicate …

First make two lists of all script URIs you want be ignored or not ignored by the rocket loader script. Then fill the `$optimize` and the `$ignore` arrays in the following script with these URIs.

```php
function rocket_loader_attributes( $url )
{
    $optimize = array (
        'http://example.com/nr1.js',
        'http://example.com/nr2.js'
    );
    $ignore = array (
        'http://example.com/nr3.js',
        'http://example.com/nr4.js'
    );

    if ( in_array( $url, $optimize ) )
    { // this will be optimized
        return "$url' data-cfasync='true";
    }

    if ( in_array( $url, $ignore ) )
    { // this will be ignored
        return "$url' data-cfasync='false";
    }

    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'clean_url', 'rocket_loader_attributes', 11, 1 );
```

You can create a plugin with this code or – second best option – add it to your theme's `functions.php`.

Comment: That is a brilliant solution, toscho ... and works, technically, from a javascript perspective and a WordPress perspective.

For some unknown reason, however, it just doesn't work the way CloudFlare is set up.  The html output looks as it should, with  data-cfasync='true' showing.  But without the "quotation marks", it doesn't invoke CloudFlare's rocketscript async functionality, so it remains text/javascript, not text/rocketscript.  

But you're definitely on to something, and perhaps something can still be done with this solution, which was brilliant.

Comment: yes this is the best practice ti have seen till no for this issue. but the problem is that the ignore list for some reason it is ignored from rocket loader but also  the script is nor working on wordpress!

Comment: According to Cloudflare: data-cfasync="[bool]" needs to come before the src attribute.  
Note: The 'data-cfasync' attribute must be added to the HTML script tag before the 'src' attribute (adding the attribute via JavaScript is not sufficient).

Comment: @AndyGee See the linked answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38319/how-to-add-defer-defer-tag-in-plugin-javascripts/38335#38335 – this is possible too (albeit a rather weird restriction from Cloudflare's side).

Comment: @toscho Unfortunately that also adds the defer attribute after the src and it can't be switched around because it occurs inside the src attr `<script src="[ replacing stuff in here] ">`. I'll figure something, possibly completely diabolical and post it here.

Comment: @AndyGee No, it doesn't See the linked answer!