# wp_register_script Question

Tags: jquery, javascript

I need to add the following JS to the head, but I don't know how to add the "data-cfasync="false" " by using "wp_register_script" or "wp_enqueue_scripts". Please help!!

```
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="http://use.typekit.com/YOUR-KIT-ID.js"></script>
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
```

Comment: Your question is similar to: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38319/how-to-add-defer-defer-tag-in-plugin-javascripts The answer there will cover your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to add it in the `head`, then this might help you:

```
<?php
add_action('wp_head', 'add_attr');
function add_attr(){
    ?>
        <script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="http://use.typekit.com/YOUR-KIT-ID.js"></script>
        <script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Make sure your theme has the `wp_head` function call. You'll need `wp_enqueue_scripts` or `wp_register_scripts` only if your JS code in in some other `.js` file and you need to call it on some page.

Comment: Should I place this code to the 'header.php' file in the 'themes' folder?  If yes, which area should I place this code in?

Comment: @RRN paste the code in the functions.php of your theme

Comment: thanks, by the way, does it mean "wp_enqueue_scripts" should only be used when I need the JS on some page but not all??

Comment: Nope... it means when your js code is in a separate `.js` file and you want to use it, for a specific or all pages. It runs on all the pages but using conditional tags, you can restrict it to the pages you want.

Comment: Ok, so why I should not use "wp_enqueue_scripts" for the current situation? Thanks.

Comment: Because you directly want to put the script tag in the head area!

Comment: To be honest, I am still confused about this... I can still use "wp_enqueue_scripts" even on head area.

Comment: Well, depends on your requirement and understanding of the flow!