# Adding Additional Attributes in Script Tag for 3rd party JS

Tags: plugins, wp-enqueue-script

I ran into this when attempting to integrate Dropbox's [drop in chooser API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js) to a plugin I'm writing.

The API documentation instructs you to place the following `script` tag at the top of your file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/1/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="MY_APP_KEY"></script>
```

All fine and good, and it actually works when I directly paste it into the page that is called in the admin section.  But, I'd like to use some variation of wp_register_script(), wp_enqueue_script() and wp_localize_script() to pass the necessary id and data-app-key.

I've tried a couple different variations of this:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_dropbox_stuff');
function add_dropbox_js() {
    wp_register_script('dropbox.js','https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/1/dropins.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('dropbox.js');
    wp_localize_script('dropbox.js','dropboxdata',array('id'=>"dropboxjs",'data-app-key'=>"MY_APP_KEY"));
}
```

And:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_dropbox_stuff');
function add_dropbox_stuff() {
        wp_register_script('dropbox.js','https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/1/dropins.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('dropbox.js');
        wp_localize_script('dropbox.js','dropboxdata',array(array('id'=>"dropboxjs"),array('data-app-key'=>"MY_APP_KEY")));
    }
```

MY_APP_KEY is replaced with the appropriate application key in my code.  Would appreciate any direction.  Thanks.

EDIT: Also tried to do it with some jquery, but to no avail.  Tried it on document load and on document ready.  I get a {"error": "Invalid app_key"} return.

```
$('script[src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/1/dropins.js?ver=3.6"]').attr('id','dropboxjs').attr('data-multiselect','true').attr('data-app-key','MY_APP_KEY');
```

Comment: What `wp_localize_script` do is print a json-encoded object in the html output of the page. This object is recognized by the script and so you can use it. What you need is to add some attributes to script tag, and so `wp_localize_script` can't help you.

Comment: G. M. is correct that `wp_localize_script` doesn't create script attributes. But is it possible to pass the app key directly into dropbox.js? Just a guess but have you tried `array('appKey'=>"MY_APP_KEY")`?  This is the code that grabs the key from the attribute `if(!Dropbox.appKey){Dropbox.appKey=(e=document.getElementById("dropboxjs"))!=null?e.getAttribute("data-app-key"):void 0}`

Comment: Hey @epilektric Could you put that in an answer?  I'm not quite following how to implement it.

Comment: @epilektric with `wp_localize_script` sure you can pass attributes to the script. I really don't know if this will work or not, however it is not a worpress related matter.

Comment: @AndrewBartel I'm not really sure how either. Maybe this will help. http://pippinsplugins.com/use-wp_localize_script-it-is-awesome/

Comment: ***[Duplicate](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38319/how-to-add-defer-defer-tag-in-plugin-javascripts/38335#38335)*** ... or at least _very_ close to one. Currently can't get closed because of the open bounty.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38319/how-to-add-defer-defer-tag-in-plugin-javascripts).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can try to use the `script_loader_src` filter hook e.g:

```
add_filter('script_loader_src','add_id_to_script',10,2);
function add_id_to_script($src, $handle){
    if ($handle != 'dropbox.js') 
            return $src;
    return $src."' id='dropboxjs' data-app-key='MY_APP_KEY";
}
```

**Update**

i just figured it out myself that the src is escaped by esc_url, so looking a bit more i found the `clean_url` filter which you can use to return the value with your id and app key data :

```
add_filter('clean_url','unclean_url',10,3);
function unclean_url( $good_protocol_url, $original_url, $_context){
    if (false !== strpos($original_url, 'data-app-key')){
      remove_filter('clean_url','unclean_url',10,3);
      $url_parts = parse_url($good_protocol_url);
      return $url_parts['scheme'] . '://' . $url_parts['host'] . $url_parts['path'] . "' id='dropboxjs' data-app-key='MY_APP_KEY";
    }
    return $good_protocol_url;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Before being printed, the result of 'script_loader_src' is escaped, so quotes are stripped out and what you output is recognized as part of 'src' attribute and not as separate attributes. This code will put in the html markup something like `<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/1/dropins.js?ver=3.6&#039;id=&#039;dropboxjs&#039;data-app-key=&#039;MY_APP_KEY'></script>`

Comment: yea  i updated my answer.

Comment: Great! +1, but still not work... But I think a very little edit will make it works.

Comment: I've tested code after my edit and it works. Thank for teaching something to me with this.

Comment: glad you got it working :)

Comment: I think OP will be happier than you an me. ;)

Comment: Thanks @Bainternet for your help, got it working using your answer.

Answer (score 27):

Since WP 4.1.0, a new filter hook is available to achieve this easily:

[`script_loader_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/)

Use it this way:

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_id_to_script', 10, 3 );

function add_id_to_script( $tag, $handle, $source ) {
    if ( 'dropbox.js' === $handle ) {
        $tag = '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . $source . '" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="MY_APP_KEY"></script>';
    }

    return $tag;
}
```

Comment: does this execute before any JS caching takes place ?

Answer (score 3):

OK, it seems (to me) that with `wp_enqueque_scripts` is not **possible** to print the id and the app key as script tag attributes.

I'm sure at 90%, because `WP_Dependencies` is not a class that I know well, but looking at the code It seems not possible to me.

But I'm sure at 100% that using `wp_localize_script` is **not useful for your scope**.

As I said in my comment above:

> What wp_localize_script do is print a json-encoded object in the html
>   output of the page. This object is recognized by the script and so you
>   can use it.

What I've not said in the comment is that the json-encoded object as an arbitrary name that you decide, in fact, looking at the syntax:

```
wp_localize_script( $handle, $object_name, $l10n );
```

The object named `$object_name` *could* be used by the script because is in the global scope and printed in the html of the page.

But the `$object_name` is a name that *you* decide, so it can be *everything*.

So ask to yourself:

**how the script in the remote dropbox server can make use of a variable that they don't know how is called?**

So there is **no reason at all** to pass id and/or app key to the script with `wp_localize_script`: **you have just to print them as script tag attributes** as is said in Dropbox API docs.

I'm not a js developer, but I think what dropbox script does is:

1. get all `<script>` html elements in the page
2. cycle through them looking for the one with the 'id' == 'dropboxjs'
3. if that script is found, looking at the 'data-app-key' of that script
4. check if that app key (if present) is a valid one and authorize you if so

Please, note that **I don't know this for sure, I'm just guessing**.

In this way, the script loaded from the dropbox server can check your app key in a way that is easy for them and easy to implement for you.

Because in the first sentence I've said that is **not** possible to print the id and the app key in the script using `wp_enqueque_scripts`, moral of the story is that you have to print them in the markup in another way.

A way that not smells too much (when there are no alternatives) is to use `wp_print_scripts` hook to print the script tag:

```
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'do_dropbox_stuff');

function do_dropbox_stuff() {

  if ( ! is_admin() ) return; // only for admin area

  $app_key = 'MY_APP_KEY';

  // why do not create an option for it?
  // $app_key = get_option('dropbox_app_key');

  if ( empty($app_key) ) return;

  echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/1/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="' . esc_attr($app_key) . '"></script>';

}
```

Comment: Thanks G.M., I got it to work using this.  I'm interested to see if there's alternative solutions using the enqueue hooks but I appreciate all the thought you put into the answer.

Comment: @AndrewBartel I think there is no way to use wp_enqueque_scripts in your case, but if you find one, let us know! :)

Comment: your solution can increase the load on the server as you are directly making 1 more http request by doing echo. The solution is good but not optimized.

Comment: @FaisalShaikh care to explain? The `echo` statement does not any HTTP request as far as I can tell, and WordPress `wp_enqueue_script` does an echo as well (see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php#L343) Surely you could reduce the number of request by combining the script with some other script you have but: 1) the scripts exists in 3rd party server in this case 2) with HTTP 2 nowadays combining the script would reduce the performance, not increase them. So maybe I miss something?

Comment: @gmazzap you are right. actually, I have a different way to do this. We can store this 3rd part js into our server and I really don't feel that combining script can increase the load on the server.

Answer (score 1):

From Bainternet's reply above. This code worked for me.

```
function pmdi_dropbox( $good_protocol_url, $original_url, $_context){
    if ( FALSE === strpos($original_url, 'dropbox') or FALSE === strpos($original_url, '.js')) {
        return $url;
    } else {
        remove_filter('clean_url','pmdi_dropbox',10,3);
        $url_parts = parse_url($good_protocol_url);
        return $url_parts['scheme'] . '://' . $url_parts['host'] . $url_parts['path'] . "' id='dropboxjs' data-app-key='APIKEY";
    }
}
```

Edit: The only difference from the Bainternet code is, I added a condition to check if the script URL is dropbox and it is a .js file.

I'm ignoring all the other URL's and rewriting the dropbox URL.

Comment: Please add some explanation on what you change and why you changed it (or had to change it).

Comment: I know this is an old response but in your code above, did you mean to return $original_url inside the IF statement instead of just $url  ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the postings, they really helped. I did roll my own version to give it some structure and make it easier to read and update. Use enqueue as normal, use script for CSS files with a false tag at the end so that it loads at the top. Though it can probably be simplified somewhat.

```
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_attributes_to_script', 10, 3); 
function add_attributes_to_script( $tag, $handle, $src ) {

    $scripts_to_load = array (

        (0) => Array
          (
            ('name') => 'bootstrap_min_css',
            ('type') => '<link rel="stylesheet" href="',            
            ('integrity') => 'sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB',
            ('close') => ' type="text/css" media="all">'
          ),

        (1) => Array
          (
            ('name') => 'popper_min_js',
            ('type') => '<script type="text/javascript" src="',         
            ('integrity') => 'sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49',
            ('close') => '></script>'
          ),

         (2) => Array
           (
            ('name') => 'bootstrap_min_js', 
            ('type') => '<script type="text/javascript" src="',
            ('integrity') => 'sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T',
            ('close') => '></script>'
           )
    );  

    $key = array_search($handle, array_column($scripts_to_load, 'name'));

    if ( FALSE !== $key){

        $tag = $scripts_to_load[$key]['type'] . esc_url($src) . '" integrity="' . $scripts_to_load[$key]['integrity'] .'" crossorigin="anonymous"' . $scripts_to_load[$key]['close'] . "\n";

    }
    return $tag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this with my eCards plugin and it's really simple.

Here's a direct copy/paste from the plugin:

```
$output .= '<!-- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser -->';
$output .= '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/1/dropbox.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="' . get_option('ecard_dropbox_private') . '"></script>';
$output .= '<p><input type="dropbox-chooser" name="selected-file" style="visibility: hidden;" data-link-type="direct" /></p>';
```

Notice the API key is passed via an option.

Comment: How is $output used?  Echoed?  Add to wp_print_scripts()?

Comment: It is either returned or echoed, depending on your function.

Answer (score 0):

I did some checking in the dropbox.js code (v2) to see what was happening and how to best solve this. As it turns out, the data-app-key is only used to set the variable Dropbox.appKey. I able to set the variable with the following extra line.

Using the javascript example on the Dropbox page https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js:

```
<script>
Dropbox.appKey = "YOUR-APP-ID";
var button = Dropbox.createChooseButton(options);
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(button);
</script>
```

In my code I set the Dropbox.appKey in every place where I reference the Dropbox javascript routines. Doing this allowed me to use wp_enqueue_script() without the extra parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler way to do this

```
 function load_attributes( $url ){
    if ( 'https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/1/dropins.js' === $url ){
        return "$url' id='dropboxjs' data-app-key='MY_APP_KEY";
    }

    return $url;
}

add_filter( 'clean_url', 'load_attributes', 11, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress syntax for [script_loader_tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/) :

```
apply_filters( 'script_loader_tag', string $tag, string $handle, string $src )
```

To add any attribute, you can modify your $tag this way :

```
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_attributes_to_script', 10, 3); 
function add_attributes_to_script( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
    if ( 'dropbox.js' === $handle ) {
        $tag = '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . esc_url( $src ) . '" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="MY_APP_KEY"></script>';
    } 
    return $tag;
}
```

Which will correctly escape URL.