# Adding Dropbox dropin js using wp_enqueue_script

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script

I want to add a new Dropbox Drop In Chooser button to my site.

To include the code in a simple page you use

```
<script type = "text/javascript"
   src = "https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/1/dropins.js" id = "dropboxjs"
   data-app-key = "xxxxxxxx">
```

Where `xxxxxxx` is the dropbox supplied key for the app using the option.  I know how to add a script using `wp_enqueue_script`,  but I don't know if it's possible to add the data-app-key,  if not what the correct way to add the script call in?

Comment: I am not not using this in a Template, but rather in a plugin.  For this reason I want to add the script either from the php function or from the already enqueued js script with in the plugin.

Comment: I ran into this as well and ended up asking the same question.  Lots of good answers [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110929/adding-additional-attributes-in-script-tag-for-3rd-party-js).

Answer (score 1):

`<script>YOUR CUSTOM JS CODE</script>` inline does the same exact thing as `YOUR CUSTOM JS CODE` placed in a js file.

I see no problem with the use of your app key in a js file. There is a few points to consider here though

- If your script is dependent on the main jquery library, just remember to set the `$deps` when you enqueue your script, otherwise it will not work if it loads to early
- Make use of [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to load your script only on selected pages

This way I cannot see that your script should fail

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Dropbox support and they came back with another method to set the key which simply involves using the following javascript call, before creating the button.

```
Dropbox.init({ appKey: '<YOUR APP KEY>' });
```

I have added this to the helper script which handles the upload and passed the key down (which is stored in a standard Wordpress option field using the wp_localize_script function).