# Add attribute to link tag that's generated through wp_register_style?

Tags: functions, css

My original question was answered here: [Google Fonts giving: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25694456/google-fonts-giving-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-r)

Is there a way to add the data-noprefix attribute to my Google Fonts link tag?

My functions.php looks like this:

```
wp_register_script( 'prefixfree', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/prefixfree.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'prefixfree' );

wp_register_style( 'google-fonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,300italic,400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic', '', '', 'all' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'google-fonts' );
```

Answer, with the help of Birgire:

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', 'add_noprefix_attribute', 10, 2 );

function add_noprefix_attribute($link, $handle) {
    if( $handle === 'google-fonts' ) {
        $link = str_replace( '/>', 'data-noprefix />', $link );
    }
    return $link;
}
```

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110929/adding-additional-attributes-in-script-tag-for-3rd-party-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [`WP_Style`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php#L12) class, we find the [`style_loader_tag`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php#L83) filter, that might be useful.

Try for example:

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', function( $link, $handle )
{
    if( 'google-fonts' === $handle )
    {
        $link = str_replace( '/>', ' data-noprefix />', $link );
    }
    return $link;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: What is the 10, 2 for?

Comment: `10` stands for the filter priority and `2` is the number of input arguments we want to use in the callback function. The default is `10, 1`.