# Enqueue Script with data attributes

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script

I am looking to enqueue this script on the header of a wordpress page

```
<script src="https://js.chargebee.com/v2/chargebee.js" data-cb-site="mydomainame" ></script>
```

I know how to use

```
function wp_mk_scripts() {

    if( is_page(11) ){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'chargebee', 'https://js.chargebee.com/v2/chargebee.js', array(), '2', false );
}

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_mk_scripts' );
```

but how do I add the parameter `data-cb-site="mydomainame"` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Additional Attributes in Script Tag for 3rd party JS](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110929/adding-additional-attributes-in-script-tag-for-3rd-party-js)

Comment: I checked all the answers, nothing works for my case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try code given below:

```
function add_data_attribute($tag, $handle) {
   if ( 'chargebee' !== $handle )
    return $tag;

   return str_replace( ' src', ' data-cb-site="mydomainame" src', $tag );
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_data_attribute', 10, 2);
```

Comment: great this works fine !

Answer (score 1):

```
function wp_mk_scripts() {

if ( is_page('331') ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'chargebee', 'https://js.chargebee.com/v2/chargebee.js', array(), 2.0 , false);
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_mk_scripts' );

add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_attributes_to_script', 10, 3); 
function add_attributes_to_script( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
    if ( 'chargebee.js' === $handle ) {
        $tag = '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . esc_url( $src ) . '" data-cb-site="mydomainame" ></script>';
    } 
    return $tag;
}
```

Based on the answer of the sample thread posted by kero - However this doesn't work - i do not get the attribute loaded.