# Add attribute to script loaded by the theme

Tags: filters, javascript

I was looking for a method to add the **data-cfasync="false"** attribute to a javascript loaded by the theme itself.

My theme load the script

```
<script type="e350ac6f596d90da70624b6d-text/javascript" src='https://thegroovecartel.com/wp-content/themes/zeen/assets/js/jquery.fluidbox.min.js?ver=2.0.5' id='jquery-fluidbox-js'>
```

And I would like to have

```
<script data-cfasync="false" type="e350ac6f596d90da70624b6d-text/javascript" src='https://thegroovecartel.com/wp-content/themes/zeen/assets/js/jquery.fluidbox.min.js?ver=2.0.5' id='jquery-fluidbox-js'>
```

Basically just the inclusion of my attribute letting everything unchanged

The script is loaded by the theme with

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-fluidbox', get_parent_theme_file_uri( 'assets/js/jquery.fluidbox.min.js' ), array(), '2.0.5', true );
```

I've seen this solution [Adding Additional Attributes in Script Tag for 3rd party JS](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110929/adding-additional-attributes-in-script-tag-for-3rd-party-js) but it's 7 years old and doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Hi there! Please edit your question to include more information. How is the Script included: by wp_enqueue_script or in some other form?

Comment: @HUistSebastian it is loaded by the theme itself as it's a script used by the theme. I don't know how the theme loads it. Is there a way to see how it happens?

Comment: You can download the theme files and search for the string jquery-fluidbox-js using an editor like Visual Studio Code

Comment: @HUistSebastian edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code referenced in your question is still good. I double checked, and this worked for me:

```
function wpse_script_loader_tag( $tag, $handle ) {
    if ( 'jquery-fluidbox' !== $handle ) {
        return $tag;
    }

    return str_replace( ' src', ' data-cfasync="false" src', $tag );
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'wpse_script_loader_tag', 10, 2 );
```

(I tested with a different script handle, but that won't matter):
[image]