# Override do_item() Function to Add Extra Attribute to Scripts

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

The WordPress file that `do_item()` is in can be found here:

> class.wp-scripts.php
>   Line 142
>   Line 144

```
$this->print_html .= "<script type='text/javascript' src='$src'></script>\n";
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='$src'></script>\n";
```

What I would like to do is modify the script tag to add an extra attribute "async", see below:

```
$this->print_html .= "<script async type='text/javascript' src='$src'></script>\n";
echo "<script async type='text/javascript' src='$src'></script>\n";
```

Obviously modifying the `class.wp-scripts.php` file is a bad idea, so how can I achieve the desired result using a custom function within my child theme `functions.php` file?  I am at a real loss on this one, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This may not be possible yet, but there is a [trac on it for a future update which looks active](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22249). You could use the [`wp_head` hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) and echo out your script there with the correct attributes instead.

Comment: [this answer shows a possible method](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/38335/4771)

Comment: Thanks Howdy_McGee. Had thought of using wp_head but would rather enqueue the scripts normally. Milo, thank you but unfortunately that solution is old and took advantage of the `clean_url` function which is now depreciated. Rather `esc_url` is now used. I guess that leads to another question, can you hook in to the `esc_url` function?