# Where is script-loader.php creating JS tags

Tags: javascript

I have a script being auto created in wp-includes/script-loader.php

This is jquery that wordpress depends on as well as some plugins for the site

```
$scripts->add( 'jquery-core', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', array(), '1.12.4' );
```

I need to add `defer` to the tag where this is created, I tried removing it and moving to the head but wordpress as well as the dependent plugins break as if its totally missing.

I assume its code like this, just not sure which to change:

```
$src = $wp_scripts->base_url . "/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c={$zip}&" . $concat . '&ver=' . $wp_scripts->default_version;
        echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='" . esc_attr($src) . "'></script>\n";
```

Any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Check [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/38319/43098) out, which explains how to add defer attribute.

Comment: So where would that `script_loader_tag` code go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', function ( $tag, $handle ) {

    if ( 'jquery-core' !== $handle )
        return $tag;

    return str_replace( ' src', ' defer="defer" src', $tag );
}, 10, 2 );
```

Provided by:
[toscho](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/73/toscho)