# Unable to defer loading of jquery

Tags: filters, wp-enqueue-script, scripts

I have two render blocking JS from wordpress core. jquery.js and jquery-migrate.min.js. Following [this answer on WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/38335/153787) I was able to add `defer="defer"' to the script tag that calls for jquery-migrate and bootstrap, but doing the same for 'jquery' does not add the defer property to the script tag that calls for jquery.js

```
  add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', function ( $tag, $handle ) {
    $handlesToDefer = array('jquery-migrate', 'bootstrap', 'jquery');

    if ( !in_array($handle, $handlesToDefer) )
        return $tag;

    return str_replace( ' src', ' defer="defer" src', $tag );
 }, 1, 2 );
```

[image: jquery defer]
[image: bootstrap defer]

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', function ( $tag, $handle ) {
$handlesToDefer = array('jquery-migrate', 'bootstrap', 'jquery-core');

if ( !in_array($handle, $handlesToDefer) )
    return $tag;

return str_replace( ' src', ' defer="defer" src', $tag );
```