# How to have featured image show in standard RSS Widget

Tags: post-thumbnails, rss

Is there a way of showing featured images in the standard RSS Widget in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

This widget class uses the function`wp_widget_rss_output()`, and [there is no filter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53680/73) to change its output. So the answer is: **no**.

But you can create your own RSS widget and replace the default widget with an improved version.

Comment: rss comes from external source therefor the only answer can be "no". you can't fix what you get in the RSS in your own code, if the data is not there nothing can help.